# Creating thumbnail overlay in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, overlay

I'm trying to create a layer on my thumbnail that shows some information about the photo ,

I'm using jQuery to create the hover effect ,

But i faced a hover problem , you can check out code and preview here :

```
My JS Code :
$('img').hover(function(){

        $(this).next('.mask').fadeIn();


    },function(){

        $(this).next('.mask').fadeOut();

    });
```

**FULL CSS/HTML/JS CODE :**

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc7S8/)**
How can i solve this problem and make the jquery hover normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're getting it because you show `.mask` above `img`. Since your hover event is on `img`, putting `.mask` over it will fire the `mouseleave` event, which will fade `.mask` out again. When `.mask` has faded out, your mouse is now hovering over `img`, `.mask` will fade in and everything is repeated.

I suggest using 100% CSS for this. There is no need for JS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,
Then this code can't be fixed ?
I'll look for CSS alternatives anyway ,

Comment: How can i make the same fading in CSS

Comment: Try [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). You're already using it for `background-color` on `.mask ul.links li a`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MiniGod. You don't necessarily need to use jQuery for this, but you can. I prefer to use CSS3 methods for their speed and ease of use. I have made an overlay class and then added the transition property, which can be very useful.

```
.textoverlay h4 { 
         color: #fff; 
         display: inline; 
         font-family: 'Any Font here'; 
         font-size: 12px;  
         letter-spacing: 1.5px; 
         line-height: 14px; 
         margin-left: 8px; 
         margin-top: 51px;
         position: absolute; 
         visibility: visible; 
         z-index: 10; 
}

.textoverlay img { 
         margin-right: 22px;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out; 
         transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Keep in mind my h4 positioning is very specific to my thumbnail sizes and you might need to tinker with this.Also its important to note that this is only supported in IE 10+ so it depends on who your audience is.

I have found that [The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) has great CSS documentation for best  practices and explanations as well as for JS.vHope that helps!